# Can longitudinal studies ever be treated as having independent observations?

Tags: panel-data, independence, manova

For a statistical analyses I'm wondering if the data of a longitudinal study can ever pass the assumption of having independent observations?

For example, I am examining forest compositional change across time for various plots. In my situation, I'm attempting to perform permutational MANOVA on multivariate species abundance data (columns are different species abundances treated as variables and rows are samples (aka plots)). In this design, rows represent individual plots but some rows represent data from the same plot but differ in year of sampling.

[Anderson 2001](http://entocert.net/PDF/MUVE/6_NewMethod_MANOVA1_2.pdf) suggests that his PERMANOVA method cannot be used unless multivariate data meet the assumption of independent samples. BUT...this method would be perfect otherwise for me to use to answer my questions.

Comment: What is the precise question that you're trying to ask (mainly what is the predictor since I assume species abundance is the response variable)? In general, you should be able to add a random effect of plot to your model to account for the correlation between samples.

Comment: @Jautis My main questions are 1.  Are plot types different compositionally (i.e., based on species abundances)  -- this would be based on a large between:within groups variance ratio. 2. Are plot types changing with time (i.e., is a single plot less like itself 20 years ago and to what degree), and 3.  Whether plot types become increasingly similar (in community composition) across time.

Comment: Also, I am trying to use a non-parametric permutational approach, so adding random effects are irrelevant in my case.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question and analysis plan.. Why do you want to use a non-parametric permutational approach rather than a mixed effects model? I don't see how you can capture the data-structure within that statistical framework. Also, question 3 seems much more tractable from a PCA than a MANOVA.

Comment: I'm avoiding parametric approach due to the number of assumptions that those methods assume, which are not met in my data (like MOST ecological data). I'm not interested in data transformation either. I'm interested in a MANOVA for the sake of a formal statistical test to report an F-statistic. PCA is simply a method to reduce dimensions and is not a formal stat test. Also, an nMDS is much more appropriate for EDA in this case vs. PCA (because I need to use Bray-Curtis dissimilarities and cannot use Euclidan)

Comment: Regardless...these comments are all distracting form my main question: **Can longitudinal studies ever be treated as having independent observations?**

Comment: That makes more sense then. And no, they can't unless you can show that there is no correlation within data collected from the same individual/plot from different years.